# Python script returns None

Tags: python-3.x, list

I don't understand why these small python script returns None. Python 3.7
Someone can explain? Thanks

```
def add_to_list(my_list):
    return my_list.append('c')

lista=[1,2,3]
lista=add_to_list(lista)
print(lista)
```

Comment: you can skip the assignment, python lists are mutable.

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are mutable. Don't need to return anything, performing modifications to the list in the function will be visible to a passed argument outside the function's scope.

```
def add_to_list(my_list):
    my_list.append('c')

lista=[1,2,3]
add_to_list(lista)
print(lista)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 'c']
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def add_to_list(my_list):
    my_list.append('c')
    return my_list

lista=[1,2,3]
lista=add_to_list(lista)
print(lista)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'c']
```